# Can't acces wp-admin of wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, wp-admin

All of a sudden I can't acces the wp-admin anymore of my Wordpress site. I've tried to change the name of the plugin folder already and I've tried to change the home-url and site-url in the database. But none of it works. Anyone else ideas what it might be?

This is the errow I get:
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to find out the error.

Go to wp-config.php file and set the WP_DEBUG to true.

Or You can check the error log file in your root folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where can I find the logs if WP-DEBUG is set to true? And I can't find the error log file in my root folder.

Comment: When you set the WP_DEBUG to true, it will show the error on the corresponding page. Seems your hosting server do not generate any error_log file in root folder so you check the log inside the var/log/apache2 or var/log/httpd folder.

Comment: I've used:, define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );, define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );, define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );. And I googled why de logs don't show up, but I can't make it work. What might be going on here? :(